# Attach PDF created using HTML div in an email (Java)

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jakarta-mail

I need to make use of the contents of an HTML div tag and create a PDF from it while I maintain the css associated with the contents.

I am using Java at the back-end to send emails, so I want to be able to attach this PDF with the CSS intact and send it along with the email.

I really need some help as to how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

```
> This sample code will help you an dgive u an idea.     <?php
>     /*
>     mPDF: Generate PDF from HTML/CSS (Complete Code)
>     */
>     require_once( 'mpdf/mpdf.php'); // Include mdpf
>     $stylesheet = file_get_contents('assets/css/pdf.css'); // Get css content
>     $html = '<div id="pdf-content">
>                   Your PDF Content goes here (Text/HTML)
>              </div>';
>     // Setup PDF
>     $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L'); // New PDF object with encoding & page size
>     $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch'; // Set pdf top margin to stretch to avoid content overlapping
>     $mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch'; // Set pdf bottom margin to stretch to avoid content overlapping
>     // PDF header content
>     $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div class="pdf-header">
>                               <img class="left" src="assets/img/pdf_header.png"/>                      
>                           </div>'); 
>     // PDF footer content                      
>     $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div class="pdf-footer">
>                             <a href="http://www.lubus.in">www.lubus.in</a>
>                           </div>'); 
>      
>     $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); // Writing style to pdf
>     $mpdf->WriteHTML($html); // Writing html to pdf
>     // FOR EMAIL
>     $content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S'); // Saving pdf to attach to email 
>     $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
>     // Email settings
>     $mailto = $email;
>     $from_name = 'LUBUS PDF Test';
>     $from_mail = 'email@domain.com';
>     $replyto = 'email@domain.com';
>     $uid = md5(uniqid(time())); 
>     $subject = 'mdpf email with PDF';
>     $message = 'Download the attached pdf';
>     $filename = 'lubus_mpdf_demo.pdf';
>     $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
>     $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
>     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
>     $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
>     $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
>     $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
>     $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
>     $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
>     $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
>     $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
>     $header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
>     $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
>     $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
>     $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
>     $header .= "--".$uid."--";
>     $is_sent = @mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
>     //$mpdf->Output(); // For sending Output to browser
>     $mpdf->Output('lubus_mdpf_demo.pdf','D'); // For Download
>     exit;
>     ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to create pdf in javascript and pass it to server side code or create pdf on server side and then attach along with mail?

Comment: Both the ways are fine. Whichever way you get your code working is correct. I would create a pdf on server side and then attach alonf with mail. Please upvote if this answer helped. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea of how to accomplish this in java? i did read about iText, not sure though.

Comment: Also I am using bootstrap 3 for css. I dunno how that will work on server side.

Comment: Use PHP, I've enjoyed both dompdf.ca and html2pdf.com. Pass them the string of your html and there it is you get the pdf. Not sure about bootstrap 3 for css.

Comment: I need to do this in java and I have tables that are formatted using bootstrap , so I need a solution that works well with bootstrap css.